# Variables Lifetime or Usage Graph

Tags: c++, c, doxygen

I there a way to generate a **variable lifetime** or **variable usage** graph such as the call graph generated by **doxygen** tool , for a large C++ project , something other than dependency graph.?
for instance variables used in multiple files

Comment: I think a thing like an architecture with multiple shared_ptr would be the anwer to your question....

Comment: I don't get exactly what do you mean, can you elaborate more on that ?